# Bootstrap Button is not showing well in mozilla firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox

check image

[image]

in image,ok button is not showing well,it will fine after 1 or 2 second automatically after showing,the problem is only find in mozilla firefox

Comment: Sounds like a transform-related thing to me. Are there any `transform` css properties on the modal or the button? Then try to overrule them and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks,i have checked css property,you are right problem is related tranform property,but what i have to do to fix the problem

css property

transform: translate(0px, -25%);
transition: transform 0.3s ease-out 0s;


if i remove transition: transform 0.3s ease-out 0s; then problem is solved but modal should have animated like effect

Comment: I don't know what the `transform` property does in this case (it's there for a reason), but you could trying to disable it by changing the value: `#your-modal-id .btn { transform: none; }` (or something like that).

Comment: thanks,problem has been fixed @redelschaap

Comment: I have posted my solution as an answer, can you please accept my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a transform or transition related thing to me. Are there any transform css properties on the modal or the button? Then try to overrule them and see if that helps:

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    transition: none 0s ease 0s ;
}
```